# same dataset different prediction results

Tags: vowpalwabbit

I have a very simple dataset, see below (let's call it `a.vw`):

```
-1 |a 1 |b c57
1 |a 2 |b c3
```

2 namespaces (`a` and `b`), and after reading wiki, I know that vw will automatically make the real features like `a^1` or `b^c57`.
However, before I knew it, I actually made a vw file like this (call it `b.vw`):

```
-1 |a a_1 |b b_c57
1 |a a_2 |b b_c3
```

As you can see, I just add prefix for each feature manually.

Now I train models on both files with same configuration, like this:

```
cat a.vw | vw --loss_function logistic --passes 1 --hash all -f a.model --invert_hash a.readable  --random_seed 1
cat b.vw | vw --loss_function logistic --passes 1 --hash all -f b.model --invert_hash b.readable --random_seed 1
```

then I checked the readable model files, they have **exactly the same weights for each feature**, see below:

```
$ cat a.readable
Version 8.2.1
Id
Min label:-50
Max label:50
bits:18
lda:0
0 ngram:
0 skip:
options:
Checksum: 295637807
:0
Constant:116060:-0.0539969
a^1:112195:-0.235305
a^2:1080:0.243315
b^c3:46188:0.243315
b^c57:166454:-0.235305

$ cat b.readable
Version 8.2.1
Id
Min label:-50
Max label:50
bits:18
lda:0
0 ngram:
0 skip:
options:
Checksum: 295637807
:0
Constant:116060:-0.0539969
a^a_1:252326:-0.235305
a^a_2:85600:0.243315
b^b_c3:166594:0.243315
b^b_c57:227001:-0.235305
```

Finally, I did prediction using both models on both datasets respectively, like this:

```
$ cat a.vw | vw -t -i a.model -p a.pred --link logistic --quiet
$ cat b.vw | vw -t -i b.model -p b.pred --link logistic --quiet
```

Now, here comes the problem, `a.pred` holds very different results from `b.pred`, see below:

```
$ cat a.pred
0.428175
0.547189

$ cat b.pred
0.371776
0.606502
```

WHY? Does it mean we have to manually add prefix for features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try `cat a.vw | vw -t -i a.model -p a.pred --link logistic --quiet --hash all` you'll get:

`$ cat a.pred
0.371776
0.606502`

It seems `--hash` argument value doesn't stored in model file and you need it to be specified at test step too. It doesn't matter for `b.vw` as it has no pure numeric features but comes into play with `a.vw`. I'm not sure if it's a bug. But you may report it.

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH, truf, I read your wonderful long report on `vw` github issues, that was terrific :-D